# Don't want Folx to become my default downloader

Tags: macos, download, macbook, safari

I installed Folx download manager in my macbook Pro and every time I want to download a link in safari it forces me to download with folx. How can I configure this to let me choose the downloader (default safari downloader or folx)?

Can any one introduce a better, free downloader than Folx for OSX?

Answer (score 1):

You might wanna try out [Transmission](http://www.transmissionbt.com/). Right click the torrent link (I assume you it'd torrents), download it to somewhere (maybe ~/Downloads), and right click it. Go to "Get info", change "Open with" to Transmission, then click "Change all".

Voila!

Comment: TanX for your anaswer

Answer (score 1):

Right click in Safari and choose disable plugin. done.

Answer (score 1):

You can just right click Folx icon in doc and choose disable Folx plugin.